# Signing JWT for ADFS to obtain access token

Tags: c#, oauth, jwt, adfs

I am new to ADFS, OAuth and JWT and have been looking at this for a number of days; Sorry if silly question or already been answered.

I read this guide that deals with authenticating a client using a cert: signing a JWT with a certificate and verifying with the certificate manually uploaded to ADFS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/cloudpfe/oauth-2-0-confidential-clients-and-active-directory-federation-services-on-windows-server-2016

It's kind of what I want but not quite - I would like to use certs for user authentication;  I would like to sign the JWT with a certificate unique to AD user and be able to have ADFS verify the user in AD as according to the certificate - avoiding the need to manually upload a certificate (plus avoiding the need to upload countless number of user certificates!).  Is this possible?

The other way of doing it, I was thinking of a JWKS URL with a ton of public certs but that seems mad! (Not sure how I go about producing this endpoint anyway).

I appreciate any guidance or pointing me to read articles...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a feature request to have ADFS support your bespoke idea for signature creation on the ADFS side.

To help you understand this in context to how JWT is meant to work:

JWT signatures are either:

1. a shared-secret (defined by the JWT producer) for the HMAC-based JWT implementation.
2. JWK (served by JWKS) for the RSA/ECDSA implementation, or;

Or concisely:

1. HMAC-based; shared secret, no confidentiality, claims are public
2. RSA/ECDSA; private key generated by the JWT consumer so it can securely decipher (decrypt) claims data that was encrypted by the JWT producer using the public key corresponding to the client private key. Encryption makes claim data confidential. Signatures are therefore (as already described) using public keys (accessed by the client via JWKS URL hosted by the ADFS server) to do the verify method on each end without exposing the private key in more than the location it was intended to be used for decryption purposes.

It seems to me you're after a specific HMAC variation based on sharing a Certificate intended as a *shared-secret*, and that would undoubtedly require ADFS to sign using your *shared-secret* rather than generate a shared-secret on the server.

If you are after a Certificate based Authentication (authentic identity) I would strongly suggest you look at a Certificate authentication scheme rather than try make a *modified-JWT* scheme to fit your ideas, which it was not designed for. Mostly because you do not control the ADFS source code and can not make it perform non-standard methods or use untrusted (client provided) shared-secret for signature generation when the JWT specification does not support this.

(Also you're trying to do Certificate Authentication using JWT that is an Authorization scheme in this ADFS context)